# Check if row exists in database table not working php mysql

Tags: php, sql, database, select

The code below is meant to check if a user already exists in the database. If the user exists, the user should be redirected to a failure page.

I have tried the code below and it doesn't work. The fail part if the username already exists.

```
if($Username!="" && $Password!="")
{
    $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) > 0)
    {           
        header( 'Location: accountfail.php' ) ;
    }                           
    else
    {
        $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (Username,Password) VALUES ('$Username','$Password')");

        header( 'Location: accountcreatesucces.php' ) ;
    }
}
```

How to I test if a row exists in a database table with a particular value?

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: `$username` is not the same as `$Username`

Comment: if this is your exact code, you have missed curly brace if($Username!="" && $Password!="")
{
}// end one

Comment: @gayan The curly brace is on the next line.

Comment: you should check mysql query too, first one you filter result using username='$username'.... (simple characters) and insert query members (Username,Password) you use first letter capital

Comment: -1: Not looking for errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($Username!="" && $Password!="")
{
    $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'");
```

Variables are case sensitive, `$username` should be `$Username` in your select.

Make sure to properly escape the value of `$Username` and `$Password` before inserting them into SQL strings like this or you may cause an SQL injection problem. Even better, use `MySQLi` or `PDO` to get real parameterised queries.

Comment: It is however good to shift to `mysqli` since `mysql` will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

Bad logic and variable are not the same.

You do `$Username != ""` and inside the query you use `$username`.

PHP is case sensitive.